# さくらインターネット、マルチドメイン化でphpを有効にするとサイトが表示されなくなる

Tags: php, wordpress

さくらのレンタルサーバーでマルチドメイン時にphpが動かない話は検索したら出てきましたが
webサイトが表示されなくなる現象は出てこなかったので質問しました。

wordpressを home/****/www/wp/ にインストールしており

home/****/www/ にindex.htmlがあります。

home/****/www/.htaccess

```
Action myphp-script /php.cgi
AddHandler myphp-script .php .html
```

上記の記述を追加するとページが表示されなくなります。
問題のページは
home/****/www/content/event.html です
event.htmlと同じ階層に.htaccessを書いても同様にページが表示されなくなりました。

```
<?php require('./www/wp-load.php'); ?>
略
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
略
```

その他こちらのサイトを参考に一通り作業しました。
http://planbworks.net/web/html-and-wordpress.html
マルチドメインで無い環境では正常に動作しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php require('./www/wp-load.php'); ?>
```

`home/****/www/content/event.html` に上記の記述を書いた場合、 `home/****/www/content/www/wp-load.php` を読み込もうとするはずですが、そこにWordpressのファイルは置かれていませんよね。

require の失敗は Fatal error になるので、何も出力しないままにPHPが異常終了したのだと思います。

`home/****/www/content/event.html` から見た `home/****/www/wp/wp-load.php` の場合、

```
<?php require('../wp/wp-load.php'); ?>
```

と書く必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 絶対パスで試しても表示されなかったので、勘違いをしておりました。